# Asterisk server registration error

Tags: sip, asterisk, voip

i have successfully installed Asterisk server but when i am registering user on it it shows following error:

```
 chan_sip.c:28059 handle_request_register: Registration from '"pushpa" <sip:pushp@192.254.171.97>' failed for '116.203.74.16:11344' - Wrong password
```

any help will be Great.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you're using correct username and password at your endpoint. Looks like your SIP endpoint (user) sending a wrong password.

Comment: thanks for answer but i am very new to SIP, i have installed asterisk on Ubuntu and now trying to register users for testing my installation. i don't know which password should i use ?
or it will be great if you let me know how to register user for test voice calling ?

Comment: @linux_prime, please try to set up user accounts in sip.conf like described here: https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Creating+SIP+Accounts

Each endpoint should have its own, unique login (username) and password. So, demo-alice is a username and verysecretpassword is a password (just examples) and you have to set up same credentials at your SIP endpoint (softphone, for example). In this case, endpoint will be authenticated and registered successfully.

Comment: it helped but it leads me to a new problem, do i have to add users manually all the time as this server will use for mobile apps and it will be big problem for me. Also ther is not "chan_pjsip.conf" in my installation.

Comment: @linux_prime, chan_pjsip is for other SIP channel driver, don't need to use it, you have chan_sip (sip.conf).
About users. Yes, every registering client must have his own username/password pair. But what's the task? Maybe asterisk is not a best platform for it?

Comment: i am developing a VoIP based android/ios app which is already working with openfire as im server, so please suggest what will be best platform to do it ?

Comment: @linux_prime, yes, Asterisk can be used for this. (I'd recommend to look at FreeSWITCH though...) but how your mobile app users will authenticate without their own user accounts on Asterisk?

Comment: thanks man, yeah adding user(registration) is main issue for now, if this solve then app users can be communicate without any issue. if i get any success, i will let you know.

Comment: see this, it looks like what i need:
http://www.talkunafraid.co.uk/2010/09/getting-started-with-asterisk-and-sipdroid/

Comment: @linux_prime, that's an absolutely standard scheme. He created account for his mobile phone app (sipdroid). You have to do it for SIP registration. Maybe your users will register somewhere? Some kind of client portal?

Comment: my users are registering via mobile app only, after reading his site i think we can register users by mobile app on asterisk. what do you think ?
Also some guys recommending openSip too. http://www.opensips.org

Comment: @linux_prime chan_pjsip  was introduced in Asterisk 12, current Long Term Support version of Asterisk is 11, so you have to use sip.conf. Also if you want add users in dynamically you can use [realtime configuration](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+RealTime)

Comment: @gkocjan thanks man, you are a life savior. this exactly WHAT I am looking for. i have installed Asterisk 11 and successfully added users manually in sip.conf but i am sure this what will save me. Thanks a lot.